# POST method not working but GET method working when using CORS Node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mern

I want to POST the data from body to mongodb but when i use CORS then i am not able to post the data , GET method in working. What configuration we have to make in CORS middleware

Comment: Context would be useful here. Use cors is too broad to let anyone help you. What are you trying now? What is the error?

Comment: I am trying to POST data to mongo db using express js, but 'Cannot POST /url' is showing , i am using MERN stack,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931135/cannot-post-error-using-express

Answer (score 0):

This error and resolution came up as the first result of my google query using your error message and expressjs [Cannot POST / error using express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931135/cannot-post-error-using-express)

Comment: Generally when i post data to mongo using express js.. It always work.. but as i start using CORS the post method not working