# Cannot POST /addfriend error using Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create a simple form handler using express. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931135/cannot-post-error-using-express) is a similar question but I can't related it with my problem. I have written all of my file [Here](https://goor.me/5hU2h) anyone can check it by using all of my file. For better understanding I copy my code here: 
**app.js code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//routes
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send('This is root dir');
});

app.get('/friends',function(req,res){
    var friends=['sakib','emon','rayhan'];
    res.render('friends.ejs',{friends:friends});
});

app.get('/addfriend',function(req,res){
    res.send('ADD friend page launch!!!!!');
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("server has started on port 3000!!!");
});
```

**ejs(friends.ejs) code:**

```
<h1>Here is list of your Friend:</h1>

<%friends.forEach(function(friend){%>
<li><%=friend%></li>
<%});%>

<form action="/addfriend" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="friend" placeholder="name">
    <button>
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

When I type any name in the [input box](https://postproblem-zygte.run.goorm.io/friends) and clicked Submit it didn't post to `/addfriend`. I didn't understand where is my problem. Please goto [input box(link)](https://postproblem-zygte.run.goorm.io/friends) after started the server.

For better understand what's my actual problem is then please use [goorm IDE(shared file)](https://goor.me/5hU2h) where I uploaded everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `get` request instead of `post` for addfriend.

```
app.post('/addfriend',function(req,res){
    console.log("I'm called wohoo!");
    res.send('ADD friend page launch!!!!!');
});
```

Comment: seriously!!! I didn't notice it and waste my time thinking what's the problem :) Thanks @Emil