# nodeMailer in Node.js return “Cannot POST / nameOfPage”

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
exports.contact=function(req,res) {
   if (req.method == "POST" && req.body.name && req.body.email && req.body.subject && req.body.message) {
      var mailOptions = {
         from: email@email1.com,
         to: email.email2.com,
         subject: "Subject",
         text: "HELLO!"
      };
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
         if (error) {
            res.render('landing.ejs', { message: "Message isn't send", level: "error" } );
            winston.info("Contact email error for user " + req.body.email);
         } else {
            res.render('landing.ejs', { message: "Message is send", level: "success" } );
            winston.info("Contact email success for user " + req.body.email);
         }
      });
   } else {
      res.render('landing.ejs', { message: "", level: "success" });  // OPEN INDEX
      winston.info("Redirect to landing page after contact form");
  }
};
```

If I use Chrome and send the email, the error returns `Cannot POST /customers` (customers is the name of the page) in a blank page but the email is sent, then if I reload the page and try again, it works correctly without error. While on other browsers it just doesn't work and only returns the error `Cannot POST /customers` in a blank page. Can anyone help me to prevent the error from returning to me?

This is my app.js:

```
let express = require('express');
let session = require('express-session');
let app = express();
let http = require('http');
let path = require('path');
let dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
let bodyParser=require("body-parser");
let winston = require('./helpers/winston'); // Log module
let fileUpload = require('express-fileupload'); // Upload file module
//var methodOverride = require('method-override');

global.site = process.env.SITE_URL;
global.site_qrcode = process.env.SITE_QRCODE;

let routes = require('./routes');
let user = require('./routes/user');

let dbConfig = require('./db/dbConfig');
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : dbConfig.host,
  port     : dbConfig.port,
  user     : dbConfig.user,
  password : dbConfig.password,
  database : dbConfig.database,
});

connection.connect();
global.db = connection;
winston.info("Database listen on port " + dbConfig.port);

let server_port = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 8080;
app.set('port', server_port);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 600000,
  }
}));
```

Comment: Can't see `req` and `res` defined in the function? How are you accessing them?

Comment: @MarcusMelodious I'm sorry, I have just modify the code

Comment: Well, you will have to share more info. How are your routes set? What middlewares are you using? Are you using bodyParser? Checkout the top answer to this question and see if it solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931135/cannot-post-error-using-express

Comment: @MarcusMelodious yes I use bodyParser! No the link doesn't help me :(

Comment: @MarcusMelodious I have update my question with my "app.js"