# Learning Node & Express - stumped on Post route not found error

Tags: node.js, api, express, postman

I am VERY new to the world of API and web development in general. I'm currently trying to post data to fake data I have in my code.

When I use postman to GET the data, it works. When I try to POST the data, I get a 404 error.

Any advice would be great..again, I am VERY new to all of this so please be gentle with this baby coder.

````
const app = express();
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

const PORT = 3000;

//middleware
app.use(express.json());

let bountyHunter = [
  {
    firstName: "Dirty",
    lastName: "Bubble",
    living: true,
    bountyAmount: 4000,
    type: "Bubble",
    _id: uuidv4(),
  },
  {
    firstName: "Man",
    lastName: "Ray",
    living: true,
    bountyAmount: 1000,
    type: "Humanoid",
    _id: uuidv4(),
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sinister",
    lastName: "Slug",
    living: true,
    bountyAmount: 500,
    type: "Slug",
    _id: uuidv4(),
  },
];

//GET Route
app.get("/bountyHunter", (req, res) => {
  res.send(bountyHunter);
});

//POST Route
app.post("/bountyHunter", (req, res) => {
res.send(`Successfully added to the database`);
});

// server startup logic
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App started on port: ${PORT}`);
});```
````

Comment: How do you send the POST request? The server code looks good to me.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh I was sending it via Postman the POST method localhost:3000/bountyHunter  - what I get back in response is ```<body>
 <pre>Cannot POST /bountyHunter</pre>
</body>```

Comment: Very weird, it's all good what you did. Can you restart the Nodejs application then resend the request in Postman?

Comment: This answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931135/cannot-post-error-using-express